# Parameter 0 of constructor could not be found - Spring Boot and Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa, tomcat7

My app was running with directly with spring container, now, i did some modifications to deploy with Tomcat server. after change my main method and add the spring tomcat dependencies, i'm receiving the error above:

```
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Parameter 0 of constructor in IntegraLogger.Controller.Service.ItagConfigService required a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' that could not be found.


    Action:

    Consider defining a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' in your configuration.
```

The referred classes are:

Repository interface

```
package IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository;

// imports

@Repository
public interface ItagConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<ItagConfig, Long> {
 ItagConfig findByName(String s);
}
```

the Service class:

```
package IntegraLogger.Controller.Service;
```

// imports

```
@Service
public class ItagConfigService extends ServiceBase<ItagConfig, Long, ItagConfigRepository> {

    @Autowired
    public ItagConfigService(ItagConfigRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

    public int countInt() {
        return (int)repository.count();
    }

    public long getIdByName(String s){
        return repository.findByName(s).getId();
    }

    public ItagConfig getByName(String s){
        return repository.findByName(s);
    }
}
```

My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.integra</groupId>
    <artifactId>iLogger</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Local Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.integra</groupId>
            <artifactId>iEtherip</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.integra</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database Dependencies -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- General Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Tomcat complete stacktrace:

```
    /home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92/bin/catalina.sh run
    [2018-12-09 12:22:39,790] Artifact iLogger:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.92
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Nov 9 2018 11:07:44 UTC
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.92.0
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            4.15.0-42-generic
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/integra/.IntelliJIdea2018.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_iLogger
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/integra/.IntelliJIdea2018.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_iLogger/conf/logging.properties
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/integra/.IntelliJIdea2018.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_iLogger
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92/temp
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 871 ms
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.92
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 118 ms
    Connected to server
    [2018-12-09 12:22:41,640] Artifact iLogger:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

    .   ____          _            __ _ _
    /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
    \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
    =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
    :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

    2018-12-09 12:22:44.617  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] IntegraLogger.App                        : Starting App on ubuntu with PID 20251 (/home/integra/Integra/iLogger/target/iLogger-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes started by integra in /home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92/bin)
    2018-12-09 12:22:44.629  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] IntegraLogger.App                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-12-09 12:22:45.305  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2018-12-09 12:22:45.317  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
    2018-12-09 12:22:45.886  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d997596a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-12-09 12:22:45.912  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1207 ms
    2018-12-09 12:22:46.118  WARN 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itagConfigService' defined in file [/home/integra/Integra/iLogger/target/iLogger-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/IntegraLogger/Controller/Service/ItagConfigService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    2018-12-09 12:22:46.134  INFO 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-12-09 12:22:46.245 ERROR 20251 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Parameter 0 of constructor in IntegraLogger.Controller.Service.ItagConfigService required a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' that could not be found.


    Action:

    Consider defining a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' in your configuration.

    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/bbb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1900)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:566)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itagConfigService' defined in file [/home/integra/Integra/iLogger/target/iLogger-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/IntegraLogger/Controller/Service/ItagConfigService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5669)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1644)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1203)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 64 more

    Dec 09, 2018 12:22:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
    SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/bbb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1022)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1900)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:566)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

(supress by the body character limit)
...
        [2018-12-09 12:22:46,262] Artifact iLogger:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
        Dec 09, 2018 12:22:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
        INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92/webapps/manager
        Dec 09, 2018 12:22:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
        INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/integra/apache-tomcat-7.0.92/webapps/manager has finished in 64 ms

i tried a lot of ways to solve or understand this problem, if someone could help me, i will be very gratefull

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add @Autowired before your parameter of constructor this:

```
    @Autowired
    public ItagConfigService(@Autowired  ItagConfigRepository repository) {
          super(repository);
    }
```

Comment: the problem keep, now i got this message error

"Parameter 0 of constructor in IntegraLogger.Controller.Service.ItagConfigService required a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'IntegraLogger.Controller.Repository.ItagConfigRepository' in your configuration."

Comment: Added the @Autowired on your parameters that you ser they are necessary

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of JpaRepository, when i changed the dependencies to run with tomcat, the JPA was modified, and in this new version there was no some methods that i was using...

for example, the method findOne() became getOne()
so, i aplied this corrections and all works!

Thanks